# Erro do TypeScript ao renderizar um componente que retorna array no React

Tags: javascript, typescript, react

Estou criando um app em React com TypeScript que faz buscas na API do GitHub.

Estou tendo problema em passar um *array* como *props* para outro componente.

A lógica seria: `User` tem `Repos` (*array* de repositórios do GitHub), que por sua vez tem `RepoItem` (objeto individual do *array*).

Mas estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> ```
> JSX element type 'Element[]' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
> Type 'Element[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': type, props, key  TS2605
> ```

Arquivo `App.tsx`:

```
return (
    <User
        user={user}
        repos={repos}
        loading={loading}
    />
);
```

Arquivo `User.tsx`:

O erro ocorre especificamente no seguinte trecho: `<Repos repos={repos} />`, no método `render` do componente `User`.

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import Repos from "../repos/Repos";
import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router";


interface IRepos {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    html_url: string;
}

interface IUser {
    user: any;
    loading: boolean;
    repos: IRepos[];
}

class User extends Component<IUser & RouteComponentProps> {
    render() {
        const { loading, repos } = this.props;

        if (loading) {
            return <Spinner />;
        } else {
            return (
                <Fragment>
                    <Repos repos={repos} />
                </Fragment>
            );
        }
    }
}

export default User;
```

Arquivo `Repos.tsx`:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import RepoItem from "./RepoItem";

interface IRepos {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    html_url: string;
}

interface IRepoWrapper {
    repos: IRepos[];
}
const Repos = ({ repos }: IRepoWrapper) => {
    return repos.map(repo => <RepoItem repo={repo} key={repo.id} />);
};

Repos.propTypes = {
    repos: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

export default Repos;
```

Arquivo `RepoItem.tsx`:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

interface IRepos {
    repo: {
        id: String;
        name: String;
        html_url: string;
    };
}

const RepoItem = ({ repo }: IRepos) => {
    return (
        <div className='card'>
            <h3>
                <a href={repo.html_url}>{repo.name}</a>
            </h3>
        </div>
    );
};

RepoItem.propTypes = {
    repo: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default RepoItem;
```

Eu fiz um teste trazendo `RepoItem` direto para `User`, e então utilizando `map` para retornar diversos `<RepoItem />` e funcionou. Porém eu gostaria de fazer isso dentro de `Repos`, e não dentro de `User`.

Comment: Quem negativou a pergunta poderia deixar um comentário sobre o motivo? Gostaria de melhorar a minha pergunta para que ela possa receber uma boa resposta :)

Comment: Dei uma diminuída no código "inútil" e fiz mais claro onde está o erro, espero que ajude.

Comment: Penso que o problema seja o valor que o componente `Repos` está retornando. Provavelmente, por alguma razão, o React espera um objeto (React Element), mas está recebendo um array. Tente envolver o retorno desse componente em um `Fragment`. Provavelmente resolve.

Comment: @LuizFelipe `Repos` está retornando um `array.map()` certo? Você quer que eu encapsule o `array.map()` dentro de um `Fragment`? Acredito que eu não possa chamar minha função `map` dentro de um elemento `JSX`. Não estou conseguindo realizar

Comment: Você pode utilizar o `map` dentro do JSX sim... Para isso, utilize `{}` para avaliar expressões dentro do JSX. Veja a resposta publicada agora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente, é um erro do TypeScript.

Conforme você pode verificar na documentação do React, não há nada de errado em renderizar um componente que retorne um array com elementos (conforme o seu componentes `Repos` está fazendo). A [documentação](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render) deixa explícito que *arrays* e *fragments* podem ser retornados de componentes:

> **Arrays and fragments.** Let you return multiple elements from render. See the documentation on [fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) for more details.

Contudo, a definição de tipos do TypeScript só considera válido os seguintes tipos de elementos (para serem retornados por um componente):

- `ReactChild`;
- `ReactFragment`;
- `ReactPortal`;
- `boolean`;
- `null`;
- `undefined`.

[Veja essa definição de tipos.](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L202)

Portanto, mesmo que seja válido pelo React, o TypeScript simplesmente não irá permitir que você faça o *render* de um componente que retorne um *array*. Pode até ser um erro das definições, quem sabe.

Portanto, para corrigir, você deve criar componentes que retornem somente algum dos tipos que listei acima. No seu caso, um [`ReactFragment`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) me parece ser o mais ideal.

Assim, basta corrigir o seu componente `Repos` para retornar algo assim:

```
const Repos = ({ repos }: IRepoWrapper) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {repos.map(repo => <RepoItem repo={repo} key={repo.id} />)}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Se você estiver utilizando `create-react-app` ou algum outro ambiente que suporte, você pode utilizar a [notação curta dos fragmentos](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta detalhada, realmente testei aqui e funcionou de acordo! Seria interessante saber se existe algum motivo maior para essa "limitação", ou se é realmente algo que não foi pensado no momento da implementação.

Comment: Provavelmente é falta de sincronia entre quem gerencia as definições de tipo e o _Core Team do React_. Já deve inclusive existir uma _issue_ no GitHub por causa disso, e se não arrumarem em algum tempo deve ser um comportamento esperado. Eu confesso que também não entendi essa falta de sincronia. Mas devo dizer que não acho mais necessário que um componente retorne um _array_ diretamente. Isso era muito usado antes da introdução dos fragmentos. Com eles introduzidos, os _arrays_ como retorno raramente são necessários. Penso que ainda é algo "válido" para não quebrar código legado.

Comment: Entendi, faz sentido mesmo. Ainda estou iniciando no typescript e não entendo por completo o porquê das coisas... Mas a sua resposta já me ajudou bastante nesse sentido, muito obrigado :)